# Chron expression and execution time on Azure Functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've scheduled an Azure function to run at `0 8 * * *` supposing it should have run on UTC time... but now it has not still been invoked... should this time be related to the Azure function region which is for this Azure function `East US 2`

The interval is set as

[image]

and the code is

```
        [Function("CheckoutRequestMoverFunction")]
#if DEBUG
        public async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%TimerInterval%", RunOnStartup = true)] MyInfo myTimer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
#else
        public async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("%TimerInterval%", RunOnStartup = false)] MyInfo myTimer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
#endif
        {
...
}
```

Before it was running every 2 minutes (it had to move a lot of data so it was scheduled that way). Not that it has to process only data from the prev day I've scheduled it to run once, but it doesn't seems.

Comment: Could you please share more details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you provided the correct cron, but on Azure Functions it contains 6 parameters. The extra one is for seconds, so if you want to execute daily at 8 am, it should be like this:

0 0 8 * * *

One thing you can do is inspect the time of the next scheduled execution of an Azure Function (time triggered based). It is stored in the *azure-webjobs-hosts* table in the Azure Table Storage. Look for the row with the partition key locks and the row key corresponding to your function with a time trigger. Click on the row to see its properties. The *NextVisibleTime* property shows the time when the next execution of the function is scheduled.

Comment: But this you wrote is not a standard chron expression

Comment: but this is how Azure Functions works